# Apply gradle file in git submodule to another gradle file in the same directory

Tags: java, android, git, gradle

I have an artifacts.gradle and an utils.gradle in a git submodule, which resides in app/submodule.

In artifacts.gradle I want to reference utils.gradle by using apply. Both files are in app/submodule

I tried naively using

```
apply from: 'utils.gradle'
```

since they are in the same folder. But gradle looks for it in the wrong directory (in app instead of app/submodule)

I can get it to work by using

```
apply from: '../submodule/utils.gradle'
```

But this means, that the git submodule must **always** be checked out into a directory with exactly the name submodule, which is bad practice.

Is there a way to reference another gradle file in the same subdirectory?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the solution myself. This works:

```
apply from: "" + buildscript.sourceFile + "/../utils.gradle"
```